# Podio API call to regenerate app token

Tags: api, authentication, podio

is there an API call (when authenticated through the standard server-side flow) to regenerate the app token?

Why? I wish to do this to improve the security for my clients so that they can (in bulk) regenerate the app tokens for all their apps. (of course they'll then be informed that other integrations might stop to work as they still rely on the old app token).

Answer (score 2):

Currently the only way to regenerate application token is through the user interface.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. A pitty. But I understand it's low priority and that it holds security dangers.